# Node JS Ajax Request Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

I have to make a query that gets me all the information from the client with a certain ID.
The problem is that I can't get the ID in the route right.
I have this ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/client',
      data: id,
      success: function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      },
```

And on the route:

```
global.app.get('/client', function(req, res) {});
```

How do i get the value of the id on the route?

Comment: you can append id to url and get it through req.body.params in server side

Comment: url:'/client/id' instead of url:'/client'

Comment: global.app.get('/client/:id', function(req, res) { });

Comment: It still doesn't work! appears as undefined

Comment: url:'/client/'+id